# how to put admob (or any other layer) above an swf flash file in webview?

Tags: android, flash, webview

I have an app that loads a flash video player inside a webview, i want to add some ads to the app using admob, but whatever combination of xml layouts i try, the ads always go behind the video.

does anyone know how to put the ads above the swf file?

my main.xml file currently looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/webview_container"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <WebView android:id="@+id/web_engine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/home_layout"
    >
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="a14f4c18e44fce4"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash in a WebView is always displayed on top of other views, you can subclass the WebView class to override the default behaviors.

```
public class WebView2 extends WebView
{

    // constructors ...

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index)
    {
        if (child instanceof SurfaceView)
             ((SurfaceView)child).setZOrderOnTop(false);

        super.addView(child, index);
    }

}
```